# Why is my server list blank/empty?

Tags: dayz-standalone

I am having trouble loading my server lists in DayZ. Everytime I want to find a server, there is a "blank page without servers."

I also cleared my server list filter but there is still no servers. Why is the list blank and how do I fix it?

Comment: Do you have any filters on? Maybe there is a filter that would stop you if your ping to the server is too high. But hey, if you want to directly connect there are ressources to find servers. https://www.battlemetrics.com/servers/dayz

Comment: @Fredy31 Hi I don't have any filters there.

Comment: I'm really out of my depth with dayz, but that might be an invisible filter. A lot of games do so so you don't see the servers on the other side of the world. Did the direct connect work?

Comment: @Fredy31 So I entered name and game port adress in the bars and after waiting like half an hour I still got no servers.

Comment: Could there be something wrong with your game? Like you got some mods installed and thus it looks to whatever servers have the same mods? Like I said I'm kinda blind guessing.